# For Google Sheets, how to open the file and it goes down to the last entry?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a job application list in Google Sheets. It's now almost 400 rows. Every time I open it, I have to scroll down to the bottom or last entry. Is there any way I can set the file up so when it opens, it automatically goes down to the last entry without having to scroll?

Comment: One possible way is to have a separate tab within the sheet where a *dynamic hyperlink pointing to the last_row* of the `Job application list` tab can be created.

Comment: OK thank you appreciate it.

Comment: You can also just hit Ctrl + *down arrow* (or Cmd + *down arrow* on Mac) to go to the last filled cell above a blank cell in any column. If you are filling every row as you go down, using this keyboard shortcut when you open the sheet will bring you to the last filled row.

Comment: Erik - this is great info, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As [rockinfreakshow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5479575/rockinfreakshow) mentioned. You can dynamically create a link that points to the last non-empty cell of a specific column. You can do it using the following formula:

```cpp
=LET(col,A2:A,
     url,"<URL>",
     HYPERLINK(
      url&"&range="&CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(ADDRESS(ROW(col),COLUMN(col),4),col<>""),-1),
      "Go to last cell"))
```

[image]

Make sure to adjust the column and to replace `<URL>` with the URL of your spreadsheet.